# How to dynamically create an array of 10 to 100 with gap of 10 between values?

Tags: php, arrays

Can someone tell me how can I create array of numbers dynamically, without any *for* loop?

e.g. I want to create array like:

```
 [0] => 10
 [1] => 20
 [2] => 30
 [3] => 40
    ..
 [9] => 100
```

Comment: Instead of "$values [$idx]", why not just use "($idx+1)*10"?

Comment: So in [tag:php] you get seven upvotes for not reading the documentation?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php). The third argument is the number to *step* between values when interpolating between the start and ending values.

```
$numbers = range(10, 100, 10);
```

Comment: Good idea, but your code will create an array with values of `1`, `11`, etc. You need to use `range(10, 100, 10)`

Comment: @alex you answer is correct with only one change. so i did that. hope it's ok

Answer (score 8):

Good answers before me, but the best, what match exactly your assignment is use [`range(start, end, step)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) this way:

```
$numbers = range(10, 100, 10);

var_dump($numbers);
```

Answer (score 6):

use

```
$numbers = range(10, 100, 10);
```

It will create and array starting with 10 to 100 with 10 steps.

Answer (score 5):

***1.You can use `for` loop like below (don't hate `for` loop):-***

```
<?php 
$numbers = array();
for($i=10;$i<=100;$i=$i+10)
{
   $numbers[] = $i;
}

print_r($numbers);
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/612601

***2.`range()` option (better one):-***

```
<?php

$numbers = range(10, 100, 10);
print_r($numbers);
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/612607

Comment: Unset($numbers[0])? Why would you do that and not just use range(10, 100, 10)? Edit: comment unrelevant because of edit..

Comment: Noticed. In the for loop you can increment $i by using $i += 10. Shorter code, just a heads up.

Answer (score 4):

You could use multiple ways.

Use a for loop:

```
$dynamic_array = [];
for($i = 10; $i <= 100; $i += 10){
    $dynamic_array[] = $i;
}

print_r($dynamic_array);
```

Use a do, while loop:

```
$dynamic_array2 = [];
$i = 10;
do{
    $dynamic_array2[] = $i;
    $i += 10;
} while($i <= 100);

print_r($dynamic_array2);
```

Use the Range() function:

```
$dynamic_array3 = range(10, 100, 10);

print_r($dynamic_array3);
```

I would suggest the range function as it is the shortest and easiest.